# React: Mutate nested states once

Tags: reactjs, typescript

So in typical programming scenarios, if you mutate an object, it mutates the object everywhere. However, in React, since states are immutable and only mutable through each's set*, if states are nested in each other, like the scenario shown below, only the currentMember's name will change, and not the version of currentMember in currentTeam, or teams. I'd have to go through each and mutate them one by one, which is cumbersome.

What would be the best way to mutate multiple states at once, or achieve a similar effect? I've done so by indexing, but it's more cumbersome to work with, and i didnt know if there were a textbook hook that fixes this.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

interface Member {
    name: string
}

interface Team {
    name: string
    members: Member[]
}

export default (props: {}) => {
    const [teams, setTeams] = useState<Team[]>([
        {
            name: 'Team One',
            members: [{ name: 'Wyatt' }, { name: 'Michael' }]
        }
    ])
    const [currentTeam, setCurrentTeam] = useState<Team>(teams[0])
    const [currentMember, setCurrentMember] = useState<Member>(currentTeam.members[0])

    return (
        <>
            <h1>${currentMember.name}</h1>
            <button onClick={() => setCurrentMember(currentMember => { ...currentMember, name: 'Zach' })}>
                Change current member name to Zach!
            </button>
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: Don't use multiple states or don't use de-normalized data? Regardless of the state shape(s) you'll have to change multiple "things" if you've de-normalized your data. If your users were stored separately and referenced by, say, ID, you'd still have to rely on that change effect, and it makes consuming code do lookups, but if it's scattered all over it's just as onerous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, you are making things a bit complicated by using state this way. You should have one base state that contains all of the teams, then reference the bits that are important to you by index.

For example, your `teams` state is fine as is. Your `currentTeam` and `currentMember` states should be indexes or some other reference to the state within `teams` you want to map to.

So, in specific terms, I'd change the format of your code here like so (forgive me as I don't write TypeScript, so I'm going to straight vanilla javascript to avoid making typos):

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'

// interface Member {
//    name: string
//}

// interface Team {
//    name: string
//    members: Member[]
//}

export default (props: {}) => {
    const [teams, setTeams] = useState([
        {
            name: 'Team One',
            members: [{ name: 'Wyatt' }, { name: 'Michael' }]
        }
    ])
    const [currentTeamIndex, setCurrentTeam] = useState(0)
    const [currentMemberIndex, setCurrentMember] = useState(0)

    return (
        <>
            <h1>${teams[currentTeamIndex].members[currentMemberIndex]}</h1>
            <button onClick={() => setTeams(teams => ({
                // Shallow copy the teams via mapping through them
                ...teams.map((team, teamIndex) => {
                  // If the current team index isn't the index we're on right now, then just
                  // return the existing team in its given place.
                  if (teamIndex !== currentTeamIndex) return team
                  
                  // If we're at this point, it means the teamIndex matches the currentTeamIndex
                  // and we need to mutate this. We'll just do that by returning a new object
                  return {
                    ...team, // Make sure we don't miss anything
                    ...members.map((member, memberIndex) => {
                      // Same as the outer map, if the current member index isn't the same as the
                      // given memberIndex, then just return the member we're on, we're not mutating it
                      if (memberIndex !== currentMemberIndex) return member
                      
                      return {
                        ...member,
                        name: 'Zach'
                      }
                    })
                  }
                }
              })
            >
                Change current member name to Zach!
            </button>
        </>
    )
}
```

As you can see, drilling that far down into an object isn't so simple, but it's possible to do without mutating the original data - you can accomplish what you are looking for by reconstructing the data on the fly with Array functions, spread syntax, and index references in state.

You might also want to consider confining this in a reducer, with a specific action containing the team id index, and member id index to make this quite a bit more composable.